# Confusions about the defination of partial in python

Tags: python

By https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html,the defination of `partial` is just as the following:

```
def partial(func, *args, **keywords):
    def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
        newkeywords = keywords.copy()
        newkeywords.update(fkeywords)
        return func(*(args + fargs), **newkeywords)
    newfunc.func = func
    newfunc.args = args
    newfunc.keywords = keywords
    return newfunc
```

I think it should be defined just like that:

```
def partial(func, *args, **keywords):
    def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
        newkeywords = keywords.copy()
        newkeywords.update(fkeywords)
        return func(*(args + fargs), **newkeywords)
    return newfunc
```

So,what's the significance of the 'unnecessary' 3 lines:

```
    newfunc.func = func
    newfunc.args = args
    newfunc.keywords = keywords
```

I really don't understand.Any advice or suggestions are appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: I think it is to keep a reference to func, args and keywords to prevent garbage collection.

Comment: @mguijarr Keep a reference - yes, but not for preventing garbage collection. Why should they be collected if they are as well in the closure of the inner function? No, they are here for easier reference from outside.

Comment: Note that isn't how `partial` is actually implemented.  It's actually implemented in C:  http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/039ac3f01c4e/Modules/_functoolsmodule.c#l90

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `functools.partial` instance provides those attributes so code can inspect the attributes to see what function the `partial` instance calls with what arguments. They aren't required for the object to do its job.